# Conditional XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this **XML**:

```
<TreeView>
  <Parent text="Installation">
    <child company="all" text="Startup" type="video" file="startup.mp4"/>
    <child company="all" text="Getting there" type="video" file="small.mp4"/>
    <child company="all" text="Steps" type="pdf_document" file="test.pdf"/>
    <child company="all" text="Pictures" type="presentation" file="pics.ppx"/>
  </Parent>
  <Parent text="Usage">
    <child company="B" text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="b1.mp4"/>
    <child company="B" text="Report pane" type="pdf_document" file="b2.pdf"/>
    <child company="N" text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="n1.mp4"/>
    <child company="N" text="Report pane" type="pdf_document" file="n2.pdf"/>
    <child company="D" text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="d1.mp4"/>
    <child company="D" text="Report pane" type="pdf_document" file="d2.pdf"/>
  </Parent>
</TreeView>
```

And this **XSLT** so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            <br/>
            <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child[@type='video']">
        <li>
            <a href="{@file}" class="video">
            <img src="play_icon.png" alt="video" title="Video tutorial"/>
            <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child[@type='pdf_document']">
        <li>
            <a href="{@file}" class="pdfdoc">
            <img src="pdf_icon.png" alt="pdfdoc" title="PDF Document"/>
            <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child[@type='presentation']">
        <li><a href="{@file}" class="presentation">
            <img src="powerpoint_icon.png" alt="presentation" title="Power Point  presentation"/>
            <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is working perfectly, as intended, but I want to add one more feature to the transformation. I want, depending on the value of *company* attribute, to include the whole element, or to skip it.

**Elaboration:** the Child elements, whose *company* attribute value is "all" must always be included in the transformed file. Afterwards, the rest of the Child elements should be grouped only if they have, i.e., *company* attribute value "B". Then I will have 3 different XSL files for the different companies. So I need the XSL code only for one company for now.

I am not sure whether I have to use somehow conditional statement or templates for that. I am just bugged, cuz my XSL file became kinda' complicated for me.

If someone can make the addition with my requirements, to the existing code - it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Milknocookiez, you can add an XPATH to your <xsl:apply-templates> to filter <child> elements: <xsl:apply-templates select="child[@company='all' or @company='B']"/>. This will only give you the wanted child elements. But how should they be grouped? Have you looked into that yet? Best regards, PEter

Comment: @Peter - Thanks. They should be grouped the same way as before. The only addition I needed is distinguishing between the *company* attribute. So If the attribute is **all** or **B** - they get grouped, and the rest are skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I use this source XML:

```
<TreeView>
<Parent text="Installation">
    <child company="all" text="Startup" type="video" file="startup.mp4"/>
    <child company="all" text="Getting there" type="video" file="small.mp4"/>
    <child company="all" text="Steps" type="pdf_document" file="test.pdf"/>
    <child company="all" text="Pictures" type="presentation" file="pics.ppx"/>
</Parent>
<Parent text="Usage">
    <child company="B" text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="b1.mp4"/>
    <child company="B" text="Report pane" type="pdf_document" file="b2.pdf"/>
    <child company="N" text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="n1.mp4"/>
    <child company="N" text="Report pane" type="pdf_document" file="n2.pdf"/>
    <child company="D" text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="d1.mp4"/>
    <child company="D" text="Report pane" type="pdf_document" file="d2.pdf"/>
</Parent>
```

and apply this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        <br />
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child[@company='all' or @company='B']"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child[@type='video']">
    <li>
        <a href="{@file}" class="video">
            <img src="play_icon.png" alt="video" title="Video tutorial">
            <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            </img>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="child[@type='pdf_document']">
    <li>
        <a href="{@file}" class="pdfdoc">
            <img src="pdf_icon.png" alt="pdfdoc" title="PDF Document">
            <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            </img>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="child[@type='presentation']">
    <li>
        <a href="{@file}" class="presentation">
        <img src="powerpoint_icon.png" alt="presentation" title="Power Point  presentation">
        <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        </img>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you get this output:

```
<ul class="LinkedList" id="LinkedList1">
<li>Installation<br/>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="video" href="startup.mp4">
                <img title="Video tutorial" alt="video" src="play_icon.png"> Startup</img>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="video" href="small.mp4">
                <img title="Video tutorial" alt="video" src="play_icon.png"> Getting there</img>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pdfdoc" href="test.pdf">
                <img title="PDF Document" alt="pdfdoc" src="pdf_icon.png"> Steps</img>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="presentation" href="pics.ppx">
                <img title="Power Point  presentation" alt="presentation"
                    src="powerpoint_icon.png"> Pictures</img>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Usage<br/>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="video" href="b1.mp4">
                <img title="Video tutorial" alt="video" src="play_icon.png"> Tilbud pane</img>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pdfdoc" href="b2.pdf">
                <img title="PDF Document" alt="pdfdoc" src="pdf_icon.png"> Report pane</img>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Consider the `<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>` in the stylesheet. In your original stylesheet you have `output=html` which causes your `<br/>` elements to "loose" the closing tag.

Comment: It works like magic! Thanks.
I just didn't understand the part with the `<br />` loosing their closing tag. What happens when they "loose" it ?

Comment: According to XHTML standards every tag needs a closing tag or a self-closing tag. Just to be on the safe side I would always make sure the br-element has a self closing tag. Best regards, Peter